# how to json encode with db oracle 10g?

Tags: php, json, oracle

this is my code :

```
<?php
$response = array();
include("konek.php");
$result = "SELECT NAMA_RS, ALAMAT, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE FROM RUMAH_SAKIT";
$statement = oci_parse($c, $result);
oci_execute($statement, OCI_DEFAULT);
if (oci_num_rows($statement) > 0) {
$response["daftar_rs"] = array();
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($statement)) {
    $daftar_rs = array();
    $daftar_rs["nama_rs"] = stripslashes($row["NAMA_RS"]);
    $daftar_rs["alamat_rs"] = stripslashes($row["ALAMAT"]);
    $daftar_rs["latitude_rs"] = stripslashes($row["LATITUDE"]);
    $daftar_rs["longitude_rs"] = stripslashes($row["LONGITUDE"]);   
    array_push($response["daftar_rs"], $daftar_rs);
```

}

```
}

$response["success"] = 1;

echo json_encode($response);
```

} else {

```
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "error";

echo json_encode($response);
```

}
?>

but json is not running properly,
display in php empty.
what should I do?

Comment: Is the code you pasted above one continuous block?  I see three opening curly braces but four closing ones.

Answer (score 0):

You never add the data to the response variable.

```
$response["daftar_rs"] = array();
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($statement)) {
    $daftar_rs = array();
    $daftar_rs["nama_rs"] = stripslashes($row["NAMA_RS"]);
    $daftar_rs["alamat_rs"] = stripslashes($row["ALAMAT"]);
    $daftar_rs["latitude_rs"] = stripslashes($row["LATITUDE"]);
    $daftar_rs["longitude_rs"] = stripslashes($row["LONGITUDE"]); 
    $response["daftar_rs"][] =  $daftar_rs; 
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add this.
but still can not?
what should i do ?

array_push($response["daftar_rs"], $daftar_rs);